# Creating small setups to deploy dll?

Tags: deployment, dll, installation

I've been using Inno Setup for deploying and registering a dll, but all the setups generated with InnoSetup have a min size of 500kb while my dll is only like 40kb.
I don't want to use a packer such as UPX because I don't like the way they work.
Is there another free app to create smaller setups for deploying dlls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Nullsoft Installer](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). Its [list of features](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Features) claims to create only 34KB overhead.

You can also write some [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) scripts to minimize the features included in your installer and bring down its size, while still using the MSI engine. (As a side note, you can also use the [ClickThrough](http://wix.sourceforge.net/ctvision.html) to have your dll automatically update)

Comment: Wow the auto update feature sounds great, I'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: I got some weird error on WIX, but NSIS worked great, and only 84,6kb :) Thanks.